# soap webservice with ASIHTTPREQUEST

Tags: iphone, soap, asihttprequest

I am trying to implement my soap web services with ASIHTTPREQUEST and i am facing some error.

Here is my code.

```
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type"  value:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"SOAPAction" value:[xmlnsString stringByAppendingString:@"GetDetail"]];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length"  value:msgLength];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request appendPostData: [yourPOSTstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and i am facing this error

```
The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.
```

i have done some googling on this and found that there is some problem with "Content-Type". i am not sure about that.

i tried this and many other option but its gives me **"Bad Request"** as a response string.

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type"  value:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"];
```

let me know if you have nay solution for this.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue ? Any hint please?

Comment: No its not solved. i drop an idea to implement with ASIHTTPREQUEST and  implemented with nomarl nsdata and connection methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type"  value:@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"];
```

Hope it works!

Comment: no its not working. it fires an exception like System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw in response string.